# Media Queries Image display none, and back again

Tags: css, media-queries

Using `media queries`: I can make an image disappear at or below a specified `width`, no problem using `display: none;`

The problem is figuring out how to do the opposite, like above a certain `width` with `display: none;`
(Say I want a small logo to only show up below x pixels..)

Tried inline style set to `display: none;` then used a query to try something like `display: visible;` no good.

Best I could figure was a hack around, initial `width` and `height:0` then use the query to reset the `width` and `height` at say,  `max-width:650px`

I played with `min-width` and `max-width` I'm doing something wrong, is there an OPPOSITE to `display: none;`  couldn't get `min-width` to do the opposite of `max-width`.

Comment: give it `display: none` by default... then using @media use `display: block` or the required display at the say 650px

Comment: Aaaah  ... (palm to forehead) display block will undo the display none... Does it matter weather the display none is inline or up in the style... I played  with both.. even juggled the order up in the style. Meaning in line style seemed to override..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `display:none/block` the `img` according to your needs

As I'm not sure what you really want here is 2 snippets:

### snippet with image showing only above 650px

```css
img {
  display: block
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  img {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/600x600" />
```

---

### snippet with image showing only below 650px

```css
img {
  display: block
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  img {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/600x600" />
```

**Note:** `display:visible` doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks Guys... That did the trick. I should have been able to figure that out.. Was up till about 5am building a site.. Brain got mushy.